# Bivariate random effect problems in selection models (Mixture Cure model)

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, mixture-distribution, multivariate-distribution

I am currently working on a mixed effects selection model.
The selection model is a logistic model with a Gaussian random effect.
The principal model is a survival model with a Gaussian random effect (lognormal frailty).

My problem is that all 30 levels of the group indicator (for the random effect) are present in the selection model.
However, due to lack quasi-complete separation (or lack of observed events), less than 30 grouping levels arrive in the principal model.

This causes problems with respect to the estimation of the bivariate Gaussian random effects distribution (the matrices in the Hessian are not equal dimension any more)... so I cannot estimate a covariance/correlation on the random effects.

Does anyone know about a solution/approach to this?
Should I drop the observations where this occurs (which will then bias my parameter estimates for the selection model) or is there another workaround (sparse matrices?).